# Multiple if statement to change sign of column values

Tags: r

I try to change positive/negative sign of column values based on multiple conditions. My dataframe looks like this:

```
DF
RS     Pub_SNP   SNP    B
rs_1    G         G     0.1
rs_2    C         A    -0.2
rs_3    A         T     0.3
rs_4    T         C    -0.4
rs_5    T         G     0.5
```

Based on `DF$Pub_SNP` and `DF$SNP` im trying to change column `DF$B`, so that

```
(please notice, code does not work, so just represent what im trying to achive)
DF$new_B <- ifelse(DF$pub_SNP=="C" & DF$SNP=="G" &
                   DF$pub_SNP=="C" & DF$SNP=="C" &
                   DF$pub_SNP=="G" & DF$SNP=="G", 
                   DF$B, DF$B) 
DF$new_B<- ifelse(DF$pub_SNP=="A" & DF$SNP=="T" &
                     DF$pub_SNP=="A" & DF$SNP=="A" &
                     DF$pub_SNP=="T" & DF$SNP=="T", 
                     DF$B,DF$B)
```

I would like to get the following output:

```
DF
    RS     Pub_SNP   SNP    B     newB
    rs_1    G         G     0.1   0.1
    rs_2    C         A    -0.2   0.2
    rs_3    A         T     0.3   0.3
    rs_4    T         C    -0.4   0.4
    rs_5    T         G     0.5  -0.5
```

Thank you for any help and suggestions.

Comment: What are those conditions? E.g. `DF$pub_SNP=="C" & DF$SNP=="G" &
                   DF$pub_SNP=="C" & DF$SNP=="C"` does not make any sense, because `SNP` cannot be `G` and `C` at the same time.

Comment: Those two columns do not come from one experiment, so those it could happen in my df.

Comment: Do you need to change the sign if both columns don't have S's or W's?

Comment: I want to create a new column in DF, DF$newB - with values of column B but with changed value sign

Comment: your `ifelse` statement returns the same value, i.e. `DF$B`. Does not make sense. I think your example is misleading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
S <- c("C", "G")
W <- c("A", "T")

new.b <- function(data){
    s1 <- data[2]
    s2 <- data[3]
    b <- as.numeric(data[4])
    sw <- ifelse(sum(s1 %in% S, s2 %in% S) == 2 | sum(s1 %in% W, s2 %in% W) == 2, 1, -1)
    return(b*sw)
}

df$newB <- apply(df, 1, new.b)
# [1]  0.1  0.2  0.3  0.4 -0.5
```

Comment: Thank you, slight modififcation and it is what i was looking for! :)

Answer (score 0):

Just throwing the correct `ifelse` approach since you tried it,

```
ifelse(DF$pub_SNP=="C" & DF$SNP=="G" |
                        DF$pub_SNP=="C" & DF$SNP=="C"|
                        DF$pub_SNP=="G" & DF$SNP=="G"| 
                        DF$pub_SNP=="A" & DF$SNP=="T" |
                        DF$pub_SNP=="A" & DF$SNP=="A" |
                        DF$pub_SNP=="T" & DF$SNP=="T", DF$B, -1*DF$B)

#[1]  0.1  0.2  0.3  0.4 -0.5
```